# When i am running the old flutter project i am getting below error, How can i fix that?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[image]

When i am running the old android project i am getting below error, How can i fix that?

Comment: Can you share your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: upload your pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your environment. You can check it from the official [example](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/example/pubspec.yaml) of the package.

```
name: example

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0-93.0.dev <3.0.0"
```